# How to get a folder directory from folder path in java

Tags: java, file, io

I need to retrieve folder from the full path by processing subDirList..which is owned using `stream<Path>` and converted into list
And ...what could be the best way to do it ?

`A\bag\cat`
I need to retrieve `cat` now how do I do it ?

Comment: Please show us some code of what you're trying to do

Answer (score 0):

So simple, File file= new File("A\bag\cat");
file.getName(); //cat

I did not understand the stream part.